# Скрыть кнопку при помощи Angular

Tags: angularjs

Есть таблица со списком работников, каждую строку таблицы можно удалить.

Как сделать чтобы последнего работника нельзя было удалить или даже что бы кнопка не появлялась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Сделать можно так:

```
<td><button ng-if="exployeeArr.length > 1"
            ng-click="deleteItem(employee)">Delete</button></td>
```

Кнопка будет доступна, только если список содержит больше 1 записи

Answer (score 1):

Запрет на появление кнопки у последней записи в таблице можно сделать так:

```
<td><button ng-if="!$last"
            ng-click="deleteItem(employee)">Delete</button></td>
```

Comment: Под последней, вероятно таки подразумевалась последняя оставшаяся запись, невозможность опустошить список.

Comment: Так даже если запись будет одна, то кнопка удалить тоже не будет отображаться)

Comment: Это понятно, но если записей больше - будет невозможно удалить именно последнюю

Comment: А все понял про что ты, тогда можно сделать так:                                                                  
    ng-if="exployeeArr.length != 1"